# Como verificar se um caracter é maiúsculo ou minúsculo em Pyhton?

Tags: python, string

Eu tenho uma *string* qualquer e eu preciso saber a quantidade de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas nessa *string*. Eu comecei a rascunhar algo mais ou menos assim:

```
def contaMaiuscula(string):
    ma = 0
    mi = 0
    for c in string:
        if(c == ????):
            ma = ma+1
        else:
            mi = min +1
    return ma, mi
```

Mas como eu vou saber se um caractere é maiúscula ou minúscula? Existe alguma função para isso?

Comment: Ana, tentou usar o método `isalpha()` ? [Python - O básico sobre string](http://www.devfuria.com.br/python/strings/)

Comment: Não, eu tentei o islower(), mas não deu certo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme documentação do Python a função seria [`isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper). Então seria isto:

```
def contaMaiuscula(string):
    mai = 0
    min = 0
    for c in string:
        if c.isupper():
            mai += 1
        else:
            min += 1
    return mai, min
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RB6Ish). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/IsUpperpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/IsUpper.py).

Tinha outros problemas no código.

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo :) tentei com o islower() tbm e funcionou

Comment: @AnaCarolinaEsteves veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado